# Mongodb aggregation pipeline how to limit a group push

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping, limit

I am not able to limit the amount of pushed elements in a group function with aggregation pipeline. Is this possible? Small example:

Data:

```javascript
[
    {
        "submitted": date,
        "loc": { "lng": 13.739251, "lat": 51.049893 },
        "name": "first",
        "preview": "my first"
    },
    {
        "submitted": date,
        "loc": { "lng": 13.639241, "lat": 51.149883 },
        "name": "second",
        "preview": "my second"
    },
    {
        "submitted": date,
        "loc": { "lng": 13.715422, "lat": 51.056384 },
        "name": "nearpoint2",
        "preview": "my nearpoint2"
    }
]
```

Here is my aggregation pipeline:

```javascript
var pipeline = [
    //I want to limit the data to a certain area
    { $match: {
        loc: {
            $geoWithin: {
                $box: [
                    [locBottomLeft.lng, locBottomLeft.lat],
                    [locUpperRight.lng, locUpperRight.lat]
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    // I just want to get the latest entries  
    { $sort: { submitted: -1 } },
    // I group by name
    {
      $group: {
          _id: "$name",
          // get name
          submitted: { $max: "$submitted" },
          // get the latest date
          locs: { $push: "$loc" },
          // push every loc into an array THIS SHOULD BE LIMITED TO AN AMOUNT 5 or 10
          preview: { $first: "$preview" }
      }
    },
    // Limit the query to at least 10 entries.
    { $limit: 10 }
];
```

How can I limit the `locs` array to `10` or any other size? I tried something with `$each` and `$slice` but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 28):

Suppose the bottom left coordinates and the upper right coordinates are respectively `[0, 0]` and `[100, 100]`. From MongoDB 3.2 you can use the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_slice) operator to return a subset of an array which is what you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "loc": { 
            "$geoWithin":  { 
                "$box": [ 
                    [0, 0], 
                    [100, 100]
                ]
            }
        }}
    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$name",
        "submitted": { "$max": "$submitted" }, 
        "preview": { "$first": "$preview" }
        "locs": { "$push": "$loc" }
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "locs": { "$slice": [ "$locs", 5 ] },
        "preview": 1,
        "submitted": 1
    }},
    { "$limit": 10 }
])
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this directly at the push?

Comment: It's not possible to do this at the push at this time @Nickpick

Answer (score 5):

Starting in `Mongo 5.2`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$topN`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/topN/#-topn--aggregation-accumulator-) aggregation accumulator:

```
// { submitted: ISODate("2021-12-05"), group: "group1", value: "plop" }
// { submitted: ISODate("2021-12-07"), group: "group2", value: "smthg" }
// { submitted: ISODate("2021-12-06"), group: "group1", value: "world" }
// { submitted: ISODate("2021-12-12"), group: "group1", value: "hello" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: "$group",
    top: { $topN: { n: 2, sortBy: { submitted: -1 }, output: "$value" } }
  }}
])
// { _id: "group1", top: [ "hello", "world" ] }
// { _id: "group2", top: [ "smthg" ] }
```

This applies a `$topN` group accumulation that:

- takes for each group the top 2 (`n: 2`) elements
- top 2, as defined by `sortBy: { submitted: -1 }` (reversed chronological)
- and for each grouped record extracts the field `value` (`output: "$value"`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by (1) allowing all values to be pushed in the group stage, then (2) adding a $filter to a subsequent $project stage.  Within the $filter, eliminate all array members with disqualifying values.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this by passing `$slice` operator directly at the `$push`.

```
  var pipeline = [{
    //I want to limit the data to a certain area
    $match: {
        loc: {
            $geoWithin: {
                $box: [
                    [locBottomLeft.lng, locBottomLeft.lat],
                    [locUpperRight.lng, locUpperRight.lat]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
// I just want to get the latest entries  
{
    $sort: {
        submitted: -1
    }
},
// I group by name
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        < --get name
        submitted: {
            $max: "$submitted"
        },
        < --get the latest date
        locs: {
            $push: {
              $slice: 10
            }
        },
        < --push every loc into an array THIS SHOULD BE LIMITED TO AN AMOUNT 5 or 10
        preview: {
            $first: "$preview"
        }
    }
},
//Limit the query to at least 10 entries.
{
    $limit: 10
}
];
```

Comment: This leads to the following error: `MongoError: Expression $slice takes at least 2 arguments, and at most 3, but 1 were passed in`