# MongoDB - retrieve only n number of documents that match a condition, is it possible?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a field in my MongoDB documents called `groupKey`.

I want to get back a list of items (easy) but I don't want any groupKey to appear more than 22 times. The total number of documents returned can be many more than 22, however each group (which has a unique groupKey) should only have 22 documents returned.

Is this possible?

I can't seem to find anything that suggests it is, if you can point me to some docs or tell me what to search that would be helpful.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594049/mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-how-to-limit-a-group-push . In a few words MongoDB doesn't support this, i.e. limiting results per group. MongoDB and especially the aggregation framework work as a pipeline i.e. you can limit the results of the whole previous step, not limit the number of the sub-results of the previous step.

Comment: Agree with @mike-argyriou.. You can't do it in Mongodb.. Better to do it in Java after retrieving the results..