# Limit results in a Mongo Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection of users and in each document there is an array of objects.

I want to group all these objects together BUT only want to return 5 results at a time. I tried to use `{$limit: 5}` but it doesn't seem to return just 5 objects.

This is my code:

```
var res = Meteor.users.aggregate([
     {$unwind : "$docUploaded"},
     {$group:{_id: null, val:{$push:'$docUploaded'}}}, 
     {$limit:5}] );
console.log(res);
```

How can I just limit it to 5 objects rather than all objects that are currently returned?

Comment: Do you want to limit to 5 groups with all the group's documents, or to get all the groups but with only 5 documents per group?

Comment: To 5 documents per group

Comment: then, your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463689/mongodb-aggregation-group-restrict-length-of-array

Comment: this one might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594049/mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-how-to-limit-a-group-push

Comment: The first link you gave worked, I had the `{$limit:5}` after the `$group`, hence it not do the limit. Thanks